# AJP exception handling - how to get a more descriptive error or status code?

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-proxy, ajp

I am connecting to another server via AJP from my apache server like below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Location /page1>
    ProxyPass ajp://mywebsite.com:8009/page1
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

In case of error, I want to use apache web servers config in modproxy like below:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.jsp
```

But when the server is down, instead of getting a status code, I only get the below:

```
net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
```

Is there a way I can define that I would like to receive a better response if AJP tunnel connection fails or if the server is down where I'm trying to connect to?